# If "not class" clicked

Tags: jquery, class

I'm creating a program that assigns a class to a randomly selected div and when you click that div it says, "You clicked the div with a class", and I'm trying to make it that when you hit a div WITHOUT the class it says "You clicked a div without the class," but I can't seem to find a way how. Is there like a jquery command that looks something like this?:

```
$(!".whatever").click(function(){
}
```

Like, a jquery command that says if you hit a div without the following class do the following?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a parent container, and then you add a whole bunch of `div`s within that? Or just a single `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's supposed to work for all div elements, target all div elements (or whatever you like really), and check if it has the class or not inside the event handler :

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('whatever') ) {
         alert("You clicked a div with the class");
    } else {
         alert("You clicked a div without the class");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(":not('.whatever')")` as a selector

```
$(":not('.whatever')").click(function(){
  alert("not whatever was clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the delegated form of `on()`

```
$('#container').on('click','div',function(){
  var self = $(this);

  if (self.is('.whatever')){
     alert('it is');
  } else {
     alert('it is not');
  }
});
```

assuming that an element with `id="container"` is the parent of all your `div` elements.

You could use `body` instead if there is no other common parent..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to both check whether a specific class is applied to the element **or** whether the element has no classes applied to it:

```
$('#element').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass(''))
        alert('Element has no classes');
    elseif($(this).hasClass('yourclass'))
        alert('Element has yourClass!');
    else 
        alert('Element has a class, but its not yourClass');
```